# Passing along application information from WSO2 APIM to specific API's

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm looking for a way to communicate the user and the subscribed application name from the WSO2 API Manager to specific API's. I already found documentation on using [JWT](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Passing+Enduser+Attributes+to+the+Backend+Using+JWT) for this, but that would imply that all connected API's get this information, something that is not desirable in our scenario.

Can the same be accomplished using some sort of mediation sequence? I can't find any proper documentation on what parameters and fields are available there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can write a custom mediation sequence like this.

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="admin--Temp:v1.0.0--In">
    <property name="UserName" scope="transport" expression="$ctx:api.ut.userName"/>
    <property name="AppName" scope="transport" expression="$ctx:api.ut.application.name"/>
    <log level="custom">
        <property name="User" expression="$trp:UserName"/>
        <property name="App" expression="$trp:AppName"/>
    </log>
</sequence>
```

Here I'm creating 2 transport headers with user name and app name.

Comment: Perfect thanks! Is there a list or some documentation of the possible variables in these expressions?

Comment: wrote a post yesterday :)
http://movingaheadblog.blogspot.com/2016/08/wso2-api-manager-how-to-retrieve.html

Comment: Great, such a list is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Hello Bee, is there a variable where I can retrieve only the domain name ?
My ask is because we have multi tenants on the apimanager and EI. We have to differentiate our environments(Dev/SIT/UAT) depending on the domain name. Our users are created as below..
user@dev.com
user@sit.com
user@uat.com

Comment: I don't think so. You have to infer that from username or publisher name.